# Checking whether any of the strings in a vector exist within an imported tab-delim file (Data Frame)

Tags: r, string, vector

I am working on a project where I have to categorize written text into numericals. My problem now is that I created some vectors containing string elements and I wanted to check whether these strings could be found within a given column of the tab-delim data frame. So I wrote this:

```
LoveIntention <- c("affection", "Affection", "love", "Love", "romantic", "Romantic")

for (i in 1:nrow(my_data)){
  if (LoveIntention %in% my_data[i,7]){
    print("it is in here")
  } else{
    print("It is not in here")
  }
}
```

This did not work as the input is expected to be one element, not several. Anyone got any experience with this? Appreciate any help!

Also, if you know how to check for case-insensitive string comparisons between the vector and tab-file, that'd be great. Kinda tired of writing each word twice with and without a capital letter.

This is an image of the column containing the strings that I want to check if containing any of the vector strings (i.e. LoveIntention)

[image]

Comment: please provide an minimal example of `my_data` with `dput`.

Comment: Have a look at `grep` where the words can be combined with `|`.

Comment: I tried "grep" and it works well. I was just curious if it works by creating a list instead. Makes the code look a lot nicer.